# Unknow Entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

My application has problem problem with find the entity by JPA.
I got the exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1184)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:50)
```

my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="JPAService" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" ></property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="***"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="***" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="***" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />            
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Exec file:

```
package test;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import testo.entities.SiecSprzedazyForm;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAService");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 

        SiecSprzedazyForm siecSprzedazyFormularz = new SiecSprzedazyForm();
        siecSprzedazyFormularz.setAdresIpOsobWysyl("192.168.0.30");
        siecSprzedazyFormularz.setDataWyslania(new Date());
        siecSprzedazyFormularz.setEmail("ada@gmail.com");
        siecSprzedazyFormularz.setImieNazwisko("ada byk");
        siecSprzedazyFormularz.setMiejscowosc("Kraków");
        siecSprzedazyFormularz.setPowiat("Kraków");
        siecSprzedazyFormularz.setTelefon("123123123");

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(em);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

is Somebody has any solution to resolve my problem with persistence.xml??

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you are trying to persist your entity manager:

```
em.persist(em);
```

When you should be trying to persist your entity:

```
em.persist(siecSprzedazyFormularz);
```

The reason it is erroring is because the EntityManager object is not a managed entity, and so it does not know how to save it to the database.